# iOS: Random does not work in every loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

So this is what my iOS program is about. After the start button is pressed, a random image of penguin will appear from the right, move to the left and fades away and repeat again and again, without pressing the start button again. I'm trying to make a different set of penguin appear in every cycle. It does loops but however, it keeps displaying the same penguin every cycle. It only changes to a different penguin when I press the start button but I want to press the button once, and when the loop goes on, different penguin appear in every loop. I put the random code in the loop but I don't see it randomizes every loop, it only randomizes each time I press the start button. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    NSArray *imageNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Right.png", @"Left.png", @"Straight.png", nil];
    Penguin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)[imageNameArray count])]];
    Penguin.center = CGPointMake(294, 373);
    Penguin.alpha = 1;
    Penguin.center = CGPointMake(Penguin.center.x - 40, Penguin.center.y);}];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.3 relativeDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    Penguin.center = CGPointMake(Penguin.center.x - 200, Penguin.center.y);}];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.7 relativeDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    Penguin.alpha = 0;
    Penguin.center = CGPointMake(Penguin.center.x - 40, Penguin.center.y);}];
    }completion:nil
    ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that all the parameters for a repeating animation are only setup once, so the random image is only picked one time. Instead of making a repeating animation, call the start: method from the completion block of the animation, and do your random pick outside the animation method,

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {

    NSArray *imageNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Right.png", @"Left.png", @"Straight.png", nil]; // There's no need to define this every time the method is called. It would be better to make this a property, and define it outside this method
    Penguin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)[imageNameArray count])]];

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            Penguin.center = CGPointMake(294, 373);
            Penguin.alpha = 1;
            Penguin.center = CGPointMake(Penguin.center.x - 40, Penguin.center.y);}];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.3 relativeDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            Penguin.center = CGPointMake(Penguin.center.x - 200, Penguin.center.y);}];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.7 relativeDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            Penguin.alpha = 0;
            Penguin.center = CGPointMake(Penguin.center.x - 40, Penguin.center.y);}];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self start:nil];
    }
     ];
}
```